# Laravel 8 : SoftDeletes not updated when deleting a user linked to a form

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, database-migration, soft-delete

I have a problem on Laravel 8 when I delete a user I have my 'deleted_at' which is updated in my 'user' table but not the 'deleted_at' of my 'forms' table because I want to delete the forms linked to this user otherwise I have an error because I display his info when he does not exist anymore.
How do I fix this problem please?

I have used the soft delete in the Models
and the 'deleted_at' is updated when I delete the form.

users migration :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('firstname');
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->foreignId('current_team_id')->nullable()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('profile_photo_path', 2048)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreignId('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('deleted_at');
        });
    }
```

forms migration :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('forms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title', 100);
            $table->text('message');
            $table->datetime('date');
            $table->string('color');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


    public function down()
    {
        // Schema::dropIfExists('forms');
        Schema::table('forms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('deleted_at');
        });
    }
```

add user to forms migration :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('forms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }


    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('forms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('user_id')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the delete code, that is not correctly reflected in the database?

Comment: destroy method in my Controller file : 
```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return redirect('login');
        }
        $users = User::findOrFail($id);
        $users->delete();
        return redirect()->route('admin');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soft delete won't work on cascading foreign keys. Cascading foreign keys is a feature of `sql` servers and soft delete is a feature of `laravel` and needs the `laravel` context to work.

When you delete it, for the soft deletes to work, you need to call delete on each model of the relation. This is quite easy with collections and higher order functions.

```
{
    $user = User::firstOrFail($id);

    $user->forms->each->delete();
    $user->delete();

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much mrhn,
Thanks to you I have learned a lot!

For those which want the function in the controller which thus makes it possible to remove the user to which belongs thus the id and one thus removes also what is related to him in my case a forms (function in the Models for the cardinalities between entity) :

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        // $users = User::findOrFail($id);
        // $users->delete();

        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        $user->forms->each->delete();
        $user->delete();

        return redirect()->route('admin');
    }
```

- findOrFail and not firstOrFail ^^'

Comment: If my answer helped please accept it, it is not within the norms to add the answer to a new answer instead update your question 